# VBA - Click on a web page element with no id only class name

Tags: html, vba

```
<div class="rightToolbarButtons">
<!--ko template: 'rightSearchDialogToolbarButtons' -->
<button class="main ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" data-bind="jqueryui: {widget: 'button',options: {label: DWResources.WebClient.SearchText}},command: commands.searchCommand, attr: { title: DW.Utils.format(DWResources.WebClient.SearchDialog_SearchButtonTooltip, $data.fileCabinetName()) }" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Search in file cabinet INVOICE  (Enter)"><span class="ui-button-text">Search</span>   </button>
```

Please see the above HTML extract i am trying to click on a "search button".
i have no difficulty with clicking on buttons with ID but i am having difficulty with tag name and unsure which tag and name i should be using.
Any help would be much appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: please show the relevant script code

Comment: use something like `document.getelementsbyclassname("rightToolbarButtons")(0).getelementsbytagname("input")(0)` or maybe ("button") not 100%

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no other search buttons you can use a CSS selector of

```
button[title*='Search']
```

Which is `button` tag with attribute `title` containing string `'search'`. 
The `"*"` indicates *contains* and `"[]"` *attribute*.

On your HTML:

[image: css selector]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the css selector via the [`.selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of `document`.

```
.document.querySelector("button[title*='Search']").Click
```